# Pass comparison operators as parameters and use directly in SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

I have a SQL stored procedure which takes several parameters. In there I need to pass conditions as `=`, `<`, `>` and use them in the query.

Currently what I'm doing is I check what's the condition and change a part of the query according to it. I want to pass the condition as a parameter and use it directly in the query.

This is how I'm doing now,

I'm passing these parameters:

```
@software_type nvarchar(50),
@software_id nvarchar(50),
@condition char,
@version_id float
```

Query:

```
DECLARE
    @BaseQuery nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT DISTINCT Installed_Software.vm_name FROM Installed_Software INNER JOIN Software ON Installed_Software.software_id = Software.software_id INNER JOIN Software_Version ON Installed_Software.software_id = Software_Version.software_id AND Installed_Software.version_id = Software_Version.version_id AND Software.software_id = Software_Version.software_id',
    @WhereClause nvarchar(max) = ' WHERE 1=1',
    @ParamList nvarchar(max) = N'@sfType nvarchar(50),@sfId nvarchar(50),@verId float,@cond char'

IF @software_type IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND Software.software_type = @sfType';
END

IF @software_id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN 
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND Installed_Software.software_id=@sfId';
END

IF @version_id IS NOT NULL AND @condition IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    IF @condition = '='
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND Installed_Software.version_id = @verId';
    END
    ELSE IF @condition ='>'
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND Installed_Software.version_id > @verId';
    END
    ELSE IF @condition='<'
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND Installed_Software.version_id < @verId';
    END
    ELSE IF @condition = '>='
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereClause=@WhereClause + ' AND Installed_Software.version_id >= @verId';
    END
    ELSE IF @condition='<='
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND Installed_Software.version_id <= @verId';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND Installed_Software.version_id = @verId';
    END
END

SET @BaseQuery = @BaseQuery + @WhereClause;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @BaseQuery, @ParamList, @sfType=@software_type,  @sfId=@software_id, @verId=@version_id;
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
IF @version_id IS NOT NULL AND @condition IS NOT NULL
BEGIN       
    SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND Installed_Software.version_id' + '@condition' + '@version_id';  
END
```

Is this possible to do that?

Comment: It would be helpful if you tagged what server you are using. MySQL? MSSQL?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `char/varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Right now, your parameter `@condition` is just `CHAR` which results in a string of **exactly ONE** character of length. So if you try to pass in `>=` as a condition, it's being truncated to just `>`

Comment: @JRLamber  It's MSSQL

Comment: What makes you think that `@condition` is fundamentally different from, say, `@WhereClause`. You already know how to combine strings together - I don't see you writing `'@WhereClause'`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not using dynamic sql for this.
I believe that the following query should return the same results as the dynamic sql version:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Installed_Software.vm_name 
FROM Installed_Software 
INNER JOIN Software 
    ON Installed_Software.software_id = Software.software_id 
INNER JOIN Software_Version 
    ON Installed_Software.software_id = Software_Version.software_id 
    AND Installed_Software.version_id = Software_Version.version_id 
    AND Software.software_id = Software_Version.software_id
WHERE
(
    @software_type IS NULL 
    OR Software.software_type = @software_type
)
AND 
(
    @software_id IS NULL 
    OR Installed_Software.software_id = @software_id
)
AND 
(
    @version_id IS NULL 
    OR @condition IS NULL
    OR (@condition = '=' AND Installed_Software.version_id = @version_id)
    OR (@condition = '>' AND Installed_Software.version_id > @version_id)
    OR (@condition = '<' AND Installed_Software.version_id < @version_id)
    OR (@condition = '>=' AND Installed_Software.version_id >= @version_id)
    OR (@condition = '<=' AND Installed_Software.version_id <= @version_id)
)
```

Comment: This is the way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

*Is this possible to do that?*  **YES**

Just add single space between your condition to avoid syntactical error

```
SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND Installed_Software.version_id ' + '@condition' + ' @version_id';
                                                                 ----^              -----^
```